# ExtJS 4.2.2 Rendering rows at gridpanel freezing screen

Tags: javascript, extjs, layout, store, gridpanel

When store associated with gridpanel loads data and put it into the grid screen is freezing during this process. I try to use **suspendLayouts()** before and **resumeLayouts()** after but this solution broke grid columns. Maybe ExtJS has other tool to keep screen responsible during render data at grid process.

Comment: Which browser? How many rows are you loading? Is it possible to apply paging to reduce row count? ExtJS 6 has improved render time for grid rows significantly, is upgrade a possibility for you?

Comment: That's for all browsers. Pagination is enabled and loads 25 items per page. Upgrade to 6 not better solution because application built on 4.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle that reproduces the issue? The time to load 25 rows into a grid should be negligible. Yes, the screen is freezing - for less than one frame (15ms)...

Comment: What you mean under "one frame"? A row or grid? Not sure that I can fully reproduce this at a fiddle.

Comment: The freeze is less time than your screen needs for a refresh of the image it shows - that is, it is negligible.

Comment: Freeze is few seconds and if at screen exist two or more grids that's really badly for UI.

Comment: Oh, that kind of freeze. Do you use like 40 columns with column width `flex`? If so, please cross-check whether the issue still occurs with fixed-width columns.